# Prevent TFS from deleting Node Modules on a build/release

Tags: tfs, build, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I've an on-premise TFS server where I am trying to speed up the CI/CD of an Angular application.  The longest part of the release process is the npm install, and the entire drop folder gets removed on each trigger (or environment release).  Ideally, I'd like the node_modules folder not be removed so the npm install just has to retrieve new packages.

I'm not able to take screenshots of the settings, so I'll do my best to describe them.

**Build**:

1. Copy Files (Contents: ***, .angular-cli.json)
2. Publish Artifact (path to publish $(build.artifactstagingdirectory))

**Release**:

1. npm install (working folder $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory/app-name/drop/projectartifiacts)
2. ng build (not important)
3. Upload (not important)

I've tried to set Clean = false, Clean Options = sources on the Build.  However, this does not seem to help.  And each time an environment is built, it still destroys the previous drop.

Any ideas on how to have the drop folder preserver the node_modules folder?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a way to keep part of the sources when cleaning the repo.

And to speed up the CI/CD, you should not enable the **Clean** option.

> In general, for faster performance by your private agents, don't clean
>   the repo. In this case to get the most performance advantage, make
>   sure you are also building incrementally.
>
> Source link : [Clean the local repo on the agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/build/repository)

However, you can check in the node_modules folder to source control if that's an option.Thus, it will be retrieved in the Get source step. Also disable the clean option for both Repositoy and Build setp.

Reference this article: [checking in node_modules](https://medium.com/@kasajian/npm-install-2a0bc73a464b)

Comment: To clarify, the npm install happens during the Release pipeline of TFS.  It seems like your answer is talking about the Build pipeline.  Is there a way to keep part the node_modules that were installed from an earlier release from being clobbered?

Comment: @MarkDeVerno No, for release It will get the sources from artifacts, before downloading artifact it will first cleaning artifacts directory. So, we cannot keep part the node_modules stayed there.